# Eclipse: ServletConfig object returns NULL on calling getServletConfig()

Tags: servlets

this is my code . Please help me solve this problem . I m new to servlet and i m trying my best to solve it but i m unable .

```
public class InsertData extends GenericServlet{    

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = null ;
        ServletConfig conf = getServletConfig(); // This is giving null everytime i m checked it in webpage
        String str = cont.getInitParameter("username");
        pw  = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html><body><b>conf</b></body><html>"); 
        }
}
```

and this is my web.xml file  :

```
 <web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>InsertData</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>username</param-name>
        <param-value>mydb</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InsertData</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How are you running the servlet?

Comment: using Apache server in eclipse .